# Not able to understand a complex parameterized return type - Java

Tags: java, generics, parameters, return-type

I have come across a snippet similar to this in Java

```
public <H extends ABC<I, U>, I, U> Set<U> get(Type<H, I, U> type) {

}
```

I do not understand this.
I only understand that it takes a parameter of the parameterized type `Type<H,I,U>` and that it returns a `Set<U>` which is the return type.
But, I do not understand the part:

```
<H extends ABC<I,U>, I,U>
```

Can anybody clarify it?

Regards,
Chetan

Answer (score 5):

It means that

- The method takes three type parameters: `H`, `I`, and `U`
- `I` and `U` can be anything
- `H` must extend `ABC<I, U>` (or it can actually *be* `ABC<I, U>`)

So presumably you have a type `ABC` which has two type parameters. This is saying that, for instance, this would be valid:

```
Type<ABC<String, Date>, String, Date> type = new Type<>();
Set<String> set = instance.get(type);
```

...because there `H` would be `ABC<String, Date>`, `I` would be `String`, and `U` would be `Date`.

Comment: Thank you. Your explanation has brought clarity .